# How set a table row's attribute class dynamically with clojure/enlive?

Tags: java, html, clojure, template-engine, enlive

I have created a table using enlive template engine. what I have done, is create a singe table row and repeated that row up to the no of row needed dynamically. But, I have some problems update the each row's attribute `class`.

How can I set the `class` attribute for every table row dynamically, say even odd manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/enlive-clj/browse_thread/thread/d2f32472ae976af8) on the enlive mailing list where Christophe Grand explains how to do this.

I also share the feeling that if [you can](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) use [nth-child selector](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) it is way cleaner.